# Python execution time

Tags: python, python-3.x

got a question regarding the execution time(probably i'm calculating it wrong even if from my point of view its sounds logic.In the last for ( at the first iteration ( when i = 0) the time is 54 seconds ~, and the next iteration i have 161 second ,third 257  and so one.. why is that ? Shoulnd the time be similar? Thanks , have a nice day!

```
import random
from Decorators.decoratorsExample import *

class BingoCage():
    def __init__(self, items):
        self._items = list(items)
        random.shuffle(self._items)

    def pick(self):
        try:
            return self._items.pop()
        except IndexError:
            return 'No more items in the list'

    def bingo_card(self):
        number = random.sample(self._items, 6) 
        return set(number)
number_of_balls = 49

bingo_round = BingoCage(range(number_of_balls))

print(bingo_round.bingo_card())
Player_with_1_card = bingo_round.bingo_card()


def bingo_check():
    picked_numbers = []
    bingo_round = BingoCage(range(number_of_balls))
    Player_with_1_card = bingo_round.bingo_card()
    for i in range(number_of_balls):
        picked_numbers.append(bingo_round.pick())
        if Player_with_1_card.issubset(picked_numbers):
            # print("BINGO after {0} balls".format(len(picked_numbers)))
            return len(picked_numbers)


record = []


@timer1
def bingo_cycle(number_of_iterations=100000):
    for i in range(number_of_iterations):
        record.append(bingo_check())
        if min(record) == 6:
            break

    print("All the balls were extracted at the minimum of {0} balls after {1} rounds".format(min(record),
                                                                                             number_of_iterations))

for i in range(10):
    bingo_cycle()
```

Comment: What is `Decorators.decoratorsExample`? Is that where your timer is coming from?

Comment: Hello, yes :) sorry to mention that its just a basic timer:                                            def timer1(func):
    import time
    def wraper_timer(*args, **kwargs):
        t1 = time.time()
        result = func(*args, **kwargs)
        t2 = time.time()
        print('{0} execution  time is {1} sec'.format(func.__name__,t2 - t1))
        return result

    return wraper_timer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The execution time of the function `min(record)` is linear with respect to the length of `record`. Since you append to `record`, its length increases from one iteration to the other. That is why the execution time of `min` increases, too.

Comment: Got it:), thanks a lot just moved it in the function and everything is fine, can't belive i've forgot him there :D, Have a nice day!